# Unable to suspend a connection of an asynchronous request while executing an unit test for a JAX-RS endpoint using DropWizard

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

Am trying to write a unit test for a JAX-RS resource deployed in Dropwizard but I am getting a javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException.

I have written down the code that I have attempted.

The below interface is placed within the project api folder structure.

```
@Path("/doPostRequest")
public interface SomeResource {

    @POST 
    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    void checkAndDoPostRequest(
        @Suspended SomeResponse response,
        @Valid SomeDetailsClass  someDetailsClassObject;
    );
}
```

I have a class implementing this interface in the service folder of the project structure as shown below.

```
public class SomeResourceImpl implements SomeResource {

    private SomeProcessor someProcessor;

    @Inject
    public SomeResourceImpl(final 
    SomeProcessor someProcessor) {
        this.someProcessor = someProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    @RolesAllowed("read")
    public void checkAndDoPostRequest(
        SomeResponse response,
        SomeDetailsClass  someDetailsClassObject) {       

      response.resume(someProcessor.doProcess(someDetailsClassObject));
    }
}
```

I have previously written Unit tests for endpoints by extending the JerseyTest class and using the target method to send a request to this endpoint. But in the case of dropwizard I am not entirely sure.

Moreover, this endpoint requires two objects, i.e., in the above interface the "checkAndDoPostRequest" method requires two objects and I am not sure how I can send both the objects using the "target" method in JerseyTest.

Here is the Unit test that I have attempted.

```
public class SomeResourceImplTest {

    private ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    private static String final URL = "/doPostRequest";

    @Rule
    public ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
        .addResource(new SomeResourceImpl())
        .build();

    @Test
    public void testPostRequest() {
        Client client = resources.client();
        resources.getJerseyTest().target(URL).request()
            .post(Entity.entity(buildDetailsObject(), 
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
    }

    private SomeDetailsClass  buildDetailsObject() {
       //code to build this object;
    }

}
```

When I try to run the above test case, I get the following exception

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Server-side request processing failed with an error.
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.InMemoryConnector$InMemoryResponseWriter.failure(InMemoryConnector.java:167)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.InMemoryConnector.apply(InMemoryConnector.java:275)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at io.dropwizard.testing.junit.ResourceTestRule$1.evaluate(ResourceTestRule.java:174)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:68)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Attempt to suspend a connection of an asynchronous request failed in the underlying container.
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:328)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
... 49 more
```

I tried appending the "async()" function in the unit test identical to below

```
public void testPostRequest() {
        Client client = resources.client();
        resources.getJerseyTest().target(URL).request().async()
            .post(Entity.entity(buildDetailsObject(), 
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
    }
```

But the above implementation simply prevents the processing exception but the doesn't run the test correctly i.e., the request doesn't hit the endpoint.

Can someone please help.

Comment: I was reading through the list of pull requests on the Jersey project on GitHub and I remember reading a PR that fixes it. Maybe wait until Jersey 2.28?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem. There is a solution for it in [this Github issue](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1099).

> Looks like InMemoryConnector doesn't support endpoints that can be suspended and are async, so a new testing container is needed. You may need to try out the Grizzly test web server. I was able to swap it out and have my test cases pass.

You should use the following line when building the resource rule and of course add the Grizzly dependency.

```kotlin
setTestContainerFactory(new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory())
```

There is code sample and more information in the issue.